# Different behaviour of QSqlite on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, database, linux, qt, sqlite

I've got a really tricky question:

I've got this Qsqlite connection in Qt, and I have some X table in the main database. I add another database with ATTACH, which happens to have a table with the same name (X).

```
So -> mainDB: X has 3 columns, syncDB: X has 19 columns
```

What I want to do is simply get three columns of the syncDB-table which correspond to THE three columns of my mainDB-table.

All is working pretty well on Windows (qt 5.something), however on Linux(Ubuntu, Qt version 4.8),

I experience an unexpected behaviour:

When I issue the following query:

```
qry.exec("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO X SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM sync.X");
```

(take col1, col2, col3 from sync.X and put it in main.X (which only has three columns)

however on linux it won't work: it says

> table X has 19 columns, but only 3 values were supplied.

When I explicitly type main.X it says no such table.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both errors indicate that there is no `X` table in the `main` database.

This typically happens when you do not use the correct directory/file name when opening the database, in which case SQLite will happily create a new, empty database.

Comment: Yes... that was it, it just hadn't loaded the main DB :D thank you very much